# Firing Polymer Function

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to fire a function in another HTML when a button is clicked.

My first HTML with the button in looks like this:

```
<template>
<paper-icon-button on-tap="_deleteConfigUsage"></paper-icon-button>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
is: "HTML1",
 _deleteConfigUsage: function(e){
 this.fire('refreshUsagesRequest');
 }
})
</script>
```

My second HTML then looks like this:

```
<script>
Polymer({
is: "HTML2",
listeners:{
'refreshUsagesRequest': '_generateUsagesRequest'
},
_generateUsagesRequest: function(e){
document.getElementById("getConfigurationUsagesRequest").generateRequest();
}
})
</script>
```

There are 3 html files involved in this transfer. The first HTML, the second HTML and a view HTML that calls them both.

In the function in the second HTML does not seem to be running when the icon is clicked. Have I done everything within the listeners correctly? Should the first function be an event?

Thanks for all help

Comment: First things first, your element names are [invalid](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements). You can't have `html1` nor `html2` as the element name. Open your console and check for errors - before doing anything else.

Comment: it's an example, those aren't the html names - they are place fillers for the actual file names.

Comment: Ok, are your elements *siblings*? Or is `html1` the *parent* of `html2`?

Answer (score 2):

Custome elements should be two or more words at least. and must be hyphen like `x-htm1` and `x-html2` as Nicholas explained above. In that case. Due to polymer 1.x or 2.x this fire functions has differences. In your case you use 1.x version. So, main aim to fire another elements function. This is also another question that if `x-html2` is child element of `x-html1` than : you should give an id name and you can call child element's function with

```
this.$.html2._generateUsagesRequest(); //html2 is id name of x-html2.html
```

However if both elements are child of a main document.(It seams like that at your example) than you may call from one child element to other child element's function:

at x-main.html;

```
<x-html1 id="html1" on-refresh-usages-request='m_generateUsagesRequest'></x-html1>
<x-html2 id="html2"></x-html2>

Polymer({
is: "x-main",
 m_generateUsagesRequest(){
    this.$.html2._generateUsagesRequest();
 }
```

at x-html1.html ;

```
<template>
<paper-icon-button on-tap="_deleteConfigUsage"></paper-icon-button>
</template
<script>
    Polymer({
    is: "x-html1",

    _deleteConfigUsage(e){  // let say u need to fires x-html2.html's function
       this.fire('refresh-usages-request');

    }
    })
    </script>
```

at x-html2 ;

```
<script>
Polymer({
is: "x-html2",

_generateUsagesRequest(e){
   // Do something as this functions fires from x-html1

}
})
</script>
```

Comment: or alternatively if your main document is not a Polymer element, you can use a simple `document.querySelector('#html1').addEventListener('refresh-usages-request', () => { document.querySelector('#html2')._deleteConfigUsage })`